# Pass data to Vue.js component

Tags: c#, vue.js, razor

I'm facing an issue with passing data to a vue component.

The `.cshtml` file looks like this:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json;

@{
    var myString = "Hello world";
    var myJsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
}

<div id="gallery">
    <Gallery my-jsonprop="@myJsonData" 
             :my-jsonprop2="@myJsonData" 
             my-text="Hello world" 
             :my-text2="@myString" 
             v-bind:my-text3="@myString"></Gallery>
</div>
```

...and the `Gallery.vue` component something like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>{{ test }}</p>
        <p>{{ myJsonProp }}</p>
        <p>{{ myJsonProp2 }}</p>
        <p>{{ myText }}</p>
        <p>{{ myText2 }}</p>
        <p>{{ myText3 }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Gallery',
        props: {
            myJsonprop: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            },
            myJsonprop2: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            },
            myText: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            myText2: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            myText3: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        },
        computed: {
            test() {
                return "Foo bar"
            },
        }
    };
</script>
```

...and finally my `main.js` looks like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Gallery from "../Gallery.vue"

new Vue({
    el: '#gallery',
    render: h => h(Gallery)
});
```

But neither of the properties is passed to the component, while the computed value of test is being displayed. Am I missing something?

Comment: How is the HTML being displayed when you choose view-source?

Comment: It just renders the container and the computed value like `<div data-v-18d88e6d="">Foo bar</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after excessive research, I've figured it out myself. It seemed that my `webpack.config.js` was missing on crucial thing for using single file components:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".js", ".vue", ".json"],
    alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
        '@': path.join(__dirname, "dist")
    }
}
```

This resolved it for me entirely!

Answer (score 0):

The correct method to pass props is changing the CamelCase variable to be a dash-case name
so in your component will be like this:

```js
 <Gallery :my-json-prop="@myJsonData" 
             :my-json-prop2="@myJsonData" 
             my-text="Hello world" 
             :my-text2="@myString" 
             v-bind:my-text3="@myString"></Gallery>
```

Please note that if you pass a javascript variable, you need to either use 'v-bind' or add a colon (:) before the prop name.

if it is just a plain text, then you don't need 'v-bind'

```
my-text="Hello world"
```

more detail about this, please check [the official vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

Comment: No, that doesn't work either. I tried to simply pass a string like you proposed to do, but vue devtools still shows the value of the property as undefined... I've updated the question to match your suggested answer